# SSH failing from Cisco routers to Dell switches

Tags: cisco, ssh, dell

Running into two separate but probably similar issues.

First issue -

I have two Cisco 2900 Series routers on firmware v15.2(4)M4 trying to ssh into a Dell 5548P stack on firmware v4.1.0.8. All attempts fail instantly with -

```
router#ssh 1.2.3.4
[Connection to 1.2.3.4 aborted: error status 0]
```

Buffer log shows -

```
SSH2 CLIENT 0: Server has chosen 2056 -bit dh keys
%SSH-3-INV_MOD: Invalid modulus length
```

If I try to modify the DH key length on the router, attempts still fail and buffer log shows -

```
SSH2 CLIENT 0: Server has chosen 2056 -bit dh keys
%SSH-3-INV_MOD: Invalid modulus length  
%SSH-3-DH_RANGE_FAIL: Client DH key range mismatch with maximum configured DH key on server
```

SSH config on router -

```
SSH Enabled - version 2.0
Authentication timeout: 120 secs; Authentication retries: 3
Minimum expected Diffie Hellman key size : 1024 bits
IOS Keys in SECSH format(ssh-rsa, base64 encoded):
ssh-rsa keystringgoeshere
```

SSH config on 5548P stack -

```
SSH Server enabled. Port: 22
RSA key was generated.
DSA(DSS) key was generated.
SSH Public Key Authentication is disabled.
```

There don't seem to be any in-depth settings related to the ssh server here that I can modify.

--

Second issue -

I have another two Cisco 2900 Series routers at a different site on firmware v15.4(3)M3 trying to ssh into a Dell N1548P stack on firmware v6.3.0.6. All attempts fail with -

```
router#ssh 5.6.7.8
Password:
[Connection to 5.6.7.8 aborted: error status 0]
```

Buffer log shows -

```
SSH2 CLIENT 0:  Channel open failed, reason = 1752134516
```

SSH config on router -

```
SSH Enabled - version 2.0
Authentication methods:publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
Encryption Algorithms:aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
MAC Algorithms:hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
Authentication timeout: 120 secs; Authentication retries: 3
Minimum expected Diffie Hellman key size : 1024 bits
IOS Keys in SECSH format(ssh-rsa, base64 encoded):
ssh-rsa keystringgoeshere
```

SSH config on N1548P stack -

```
SSH Server enabled.  Port: 22
Protocol Levels: Versions 1 and 2.
SSH Connections Currently in Use: ............. 1
Maximum number of SSH Sessions Allowed: ....... 5
SSH Session Timeout: .......................... 600
RSA key was generated.
DSA key was generated.
SSH Public Key Authentication is disabled.
```

In this particular scenario, if I modify the router to use SSH v1, it's able to connect. Using v2, it's not. Of course, we don't want to use v1. I haven't been able to figure out what reason "1752134516" means.

--

Note that I'm able to SSH into both switch stacks directly. It's only the routers that aren't able to connect.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

please try by this command to change size

> ip ssh dh min size 2048

in other wise 2048 can change to you required length of modules

Answer (score 0):

Regarding  Dell N1548P stack on firmware v6.3.0.6 and

```
SSH2 CLIENT 0:  Channel open failed, reason = 1752134516
```

Make sure it's not running OpenSSH v6.9. There is an issue with Cisco and OpenSSH 6.9 [described here](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2015-July/034239.html)

> Turns out the problem is the new protocol extension for sending host
>   keys to the client after user authentication (section 2.5 of the
>   PROTOCOLS document).  Commenting out the notify_hostkeys() call in
>   sshd.c fixes the issues with Cisco scp.  Maybe a new bug compatibility
>   flag in on order to add to the "Cisco-1.*" client string that was
>   added in 6.9?

which has been fixed in OpenSSH v7.0